Using PowerShell to modify package versions in C# Project files
I'd like to use PowerShell to modify the versions of some of our packages. Using this script it works if I just pass in the version number, but there may be other packages with the same version that we don't want to update. Primarily, the package name will begin with Utilities
How can I modify this script to modify both of these package references? i.e. I want to update the version of this package to 0.1.5.16-develop in all .csproj files in all subdirectories under the one passed in.
<PackageReference Include="Utilities.Exceptions">
   <Version>0.1.5.14-develop</Version>
</PackageReference>

<PackageReference Include="Utilities.Exceptions" Version="0.1.5.14-develop" />

PowerShell script:
$directory = $args[0]
$searchString = $args[1]
$replaceString = $args[2]

Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter *.csproj -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $fileContent = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $fileContent = $fileContent -replace $searchString, $replaceString
    $fileContent | Set-Content $_.FullName
}

I know about the solution here: Updating a NuGet package across multiple projects/solutions but we don't use packages.config files

I'd like to use PowerShell to modify the versions of some of our packages: Why? It seems that you don't know PowerShell, and aren't interested in spending the time to learn/experiment to get the desired result. Use what you know. If you program in C#, then you may consider writing a small program in C# to perform the task.

Why do you need to do it? You can easily create an MSBuild variable with version and just supply value for it when running msbuild.

Here is a way to build C# projects with customized package versions using msbuild command. The sample Csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <MyVersion>0.1.5.14-develop</MyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="MyPackage" Version="$(MyVersion)" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Target Name="PrintMyVersion" AfterTargets="Build">
            <Message Text="MyVersion: $(MyVersion)" Importance="high" />
      </Target>
</Project>

Then, enter this command in PowerShell to build the project with an customized MSBuild variable of version and you can see information of versions in the console.
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:MyVersion=0.1.5.16-develop


Given the sample Csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PackageReference Include="Utilities.Exceptions">
    <Version>0.1.5.14-develop</Version>
  </PackageReference>

  <PackageReference Include="Utilities.Exceptions" Version="0.1.5.14-develop" />
  <!-- adding other package for testing -->
  <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
</Project>

Assuming we have it in stored in the file test.xml in our current location, you could use the following filtering expression to get and update both nodes:
$path = Convert-Path .\test.xml
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.Load($path)

$packageName = 'Utilities.Exceptions'
$packageVersion = '0.1.5.14-develop'
$newVersion = '1.1.1.1'

$filter = @"
//PackageReference[@Include='$packageName' and @Version='$packageVersion'] |
//PackageReference[@Include='$packageName'][Version[text()='$packageVersion']]
"@

$xml.SelectNodes($filter) | ForEach-Object { $_.Version = $newVersion }
$xml.InnerXml

This would produce an output of:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PackageReference Include="Utilities.Exceptions">
    <Version>1.1.1.1</Version>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Utilities.Exceptions" Version="1.1.1.1" />
  <!-- adding other package for testing -->
  <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
</Project>

If you wanted to apply this logic to all Csproj files you could use:
param($directory, $packageName, $packageVersion, $newVersion)

$filter = @"
//PackageReference[@Include='$packageName' and @Version='$packageVersion'] |
//PackageReference[@Include='$packageName'][Version[text()='$packageVersion']]
"@

Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter *.csproj -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $xml = [xml]::new()
    $xml.Load($_.FullName)
    $foundNode = $false

    foreach ($node in $xml.SelectNodes($filter)) {
        $foundNode = $true
        $node.Version = $newVersion
    }

    if ($foundNode) {
        $xml.Save($_.FullName)
    }
}

